# Jquery Dialog opening multiple dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple images on the same page, for each image, when clicked, I'm trying to get a dialog box to open, I have 6 of the following in my HTML set up. CUrrently when I click an image, 6 dialogs pop-up, all with the same info found in the first div. How can I modify my script to make this work properly:
The HTML:

```
<div class="profiles">
    <a class="open" href="#">
        <img src="/../.jpg" / class="img-full"></a>
    <div class="dialog" title="Basic modal dialog">
        <p><strong>Some Text</strong></p>
        <p>
            <strong>Phone</strong>: *********<br />
            <strong>Email</strong>: <a href="mailto:some@email.com">SomeEmail</a>
        </p>
    </div>   
</div>
```

The JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: false,
            position: "center",
            width: "300px",
            modal: true,
            title: "",
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $(".open")

          .click(function () {
              $(".dialog").dialog("open");
          });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have many `.dialog` divs. Keep only one div.

```
<div class="dialog" title="Basic modal dialog">
    <p><strong>Some Text</strong>

    </p>
    <p> <strong>Phone</strong>: *********
        <br /> <strong>Email</strong>: <a href="mailto:some@email.com">SomeEmail</a>

    </p>
</div>
<div class="profiles"> <a class="open" href="#">
        <img src="/../.jpg" class="img-full"></a>

</div>
<div class="profiles"> <a class="open" href="#">
        <img src="/../.jpg" class="img-full"></a>

</div>
```

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/f2D9m/) fiddle.

---

Update: Modify you js to this.

```
$(".open").click(function () {
    var div = $(this).next("div.dialog");
    var dia = $(div).dialog({
        draggable: false,
        position: "center",
        width: "300px",
        modal: true,
        title: "",
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $(this).dialog("destroy"); //need to remove the created html. otherwise the next click will not work.
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Dont forget to add css

```
.dialog {
  display:none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2D9m/3/)

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks, but it's the dialog div's that contain the info that is needed in the pop-up.

Comment: Why is it that you can only open the dialog once, then it does not work again? Any ideas how to fix this?