# jQuery - multiple instances of dialog boxes won't open

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have the following problem:
I use dialog boxes to show different pages/content inside of them, however when two different dialog boxes are opened it crashes and they cannot be opened again. Everything is fine as long as one box is opened, it can even be opened multiple times. When I open second dialog box neither of them can be reopened. I have already tried to "destroy" the dialog on closing (as suggested here [Jquery Dialog opening multiple dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051408/jquery-dialog-opening-multiple-dialogs)) but it didn't help, I still can open only one instance of each box and when two different ones are opened it crashes and neither of them reopens.

I have something like that in html:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="link1">link1 title</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="link2">link2 title</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then in the javascript:

```
$("#link1").click(function () {
$(function ()    {
        $('<div>').dialog({
            modal: false,
            open: function ()
            {
                $(this).load('somePage.php');
            },         
            height: 500,
            width: 1300,
            title: 'title1'
        });
    });
});
$("#link2").click(function() {
$(function ()    {
        $('<div>').dialog({
            modal: false,
            open: function ()
            {
                $(this).load('otherPage.html');
            },         
            height: 535,
            width: 880,
            title: 'title2'
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$(function ()    {` is not at the right place:

```
$(function ()    {
    $("#link1").click(function () {
        $('<div>').dialog({
            modal: false,
            open: function ()
            {
                $(this).load('somePage.php');
            },         
            height: 500,
            width: 1300,
            title: 'title1'
        });
    });
    $("#link2").click(function() {
        $('<div>').dialog({
            modal: false,
            open: function ()
            {
                $(this).load('otherPage.html');
            },         
            height: 535,
            width: 880,
            title: 'title2'
        });
    });
});
```

The code inside `$(function() {…}` is executed at document loading, the perfect time to register event handler on our HTML elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately it doesn't solve it. I changed the functions' place as you said and still can open each link individually multiple times in multiple dialog boxes, however as soon as I open the second link both links stop to work and I cannot reopen them until the page is reloaded.

Comment: What behavior do you expect ? `$(this).load` ajax load the content of the page, not the page itself (use an iframe for that). What do you mean with "links stop to work" ?

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem, I could open each dialog box only once, after closing first dialog, opening second one and clicking on the link to open first dialog again it didn't work.

After trying different solutions proposed by people to clear the dialog content on closing I started digging through my (still flawed) code and found out it was because of my stupid mistake: when I was running tests on the subpage I loaded jquery directly there from external api which seemed to be different version than the one I load locally in index.html and that's what was causing the crashes.